# Add xml nodes to an xml object loaded via jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I am loading an xml doc via ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'xml',
    url: 'data/sample-data.php',
    success: function (response) {
       myClass.myData = $(response);
    }
});
```

This works great and once I have this I am able to build views on the page using the data and then have editing of that on the page.

Next, I would like to update that xml to eventually send back to the server.

I've tried multiple ways to update without luck.  Here is the one that seemed to be the closest.

```
myClass.myData.find('book[data-id="' + id + '"]').remove();

var new_xml = '<book data-id="3434">';
    new_xml += '<name>just using this as an example, would build with code</name>';
    new_xml += '</book>';
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(new_xml,"text/xml");
myClass.MyData.find('books').append(xmlDoc);
```

So, basically, I am loading an xml, allowing visitors to edit via interface, and want to update the class xml as they edit, then eventually send back to the server to save.

Comment: I would certainly not try to insert a DOM document node as a child of an element node. Try to insert an element node into an element e.g. if something makes sense (without seeing the XML structure you unfortunately have not included) try e.g. `myClass.myData.find('books').append(xmlDoc.documentElement)`.

Comment: It is also likely that simply using `myClass.myData.find('books').append(new_xml)` does the job but I haven't tested.